# Issue using sql subquery and random() to create a sample

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift

I have two datasets, baskets (11m rows) and transactions (23m rows), that I'm using to create a sample of the dataset transactions.

Datasets represent customers shopping in a store, transactions are the items a customer has bought (so in one visit there could be multiple rows if customer buys more than one item), baskets are a summary of the transactions so only have one row for each visit.

Datasets are joined by basket_id. The baskets are a summary of the transactions so the datasets are consistent

When I use a subquery to create a sample of the transactions (example below) it is returning more baskets than expected (just over double)

```
SET seed TO.25;

SELECT 
     COUNT(DISTINCT transactions.basket_id)
FROM 
     transactions
WHERE 
     basket_id IN (
                   SELECT 
                       basket_id 
                   FROM 
                       baskets 
                   WHERE 
                       RANDOM() < 0.01
                  );
```

When I split this into two steps it works as expected:

```
SET seed TO.25;

CREATE TABLE sample_baskets 
AS
SELECT 
    basket_id
FROM 
    baskets
WHERE 
    RANDOM() < 0.01;

SELECT 
     COUNT(DISTINCT transactions.basket_id)
FROM 
     transactions
INNER JOIN 
     sample_baskets 
ON 
     transactions.basket_id = sample_baskets.basket_id;
```

Comment: Couple of things.. why do you want to use Random() at the very first place? Because in this way you will get a random value which will differ each time. Second when u split, then you are making another static table which won't be having any updated data. So your results won't be actual in that case.

Comment: Random() will change but I can add a seed to ensure sample stays consistent. Regarding the split, again true it's just a quick example to try and explain the issue that Im having with the subquery, not sure what the issue is currently

Comment: well, instead of using Random(), use a fix value and see if there is any difference in expected output.. I guess you will get right data..

Comment: I'm not sure that is it. I realise there will be some variation between the two queries as I don't have a set seed at the moment, but the issue is that the subquery is bringing back more than double expected volume so can't be an issue related to the random() - please correct me if my interpretation of your suggestion is wrong?

Comment: To understand it better, instead of filtering using Random(), use a fix value and then execute ur both set of queries. Then you will see that both are working same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, so in my opinion, with the seed fixed, both approaches should yield to exactly the same result, so perhaps the question is what is happening in the subquery to cause the unexpected results? / is there another way that within one statement I can take a random 10% sample of the transactions dataset?

Comment: If you are looking for ways to speed up COUNT DISTINCT, check also APPROXIMATE COUNT DISTINCT.